# Filter out duplicates from List[Either[Object, Exception]] in scala

Tags: scala

I'm working with a list of that could either consist of an userInfo object or 
an exception. What I want to do now is to filter out all duplicated userInfo
objects. The filtering should be done on the **email** property in userInfo.
When that is done I want to return a list of List[Either[InvitePatternException, UserInfo]]

```
val filtered = list.map {
  case Success(userInfo) => Right(userInfo)
  case Failure(ex: InvitePatternException) => Left(ex)
}
```

So my question is, how and when should I perform the filtering? Should I filter on the 
List[Either[InvitePatternException, UserInfo]] or before? 
What is the scala way of doing this?

Comment: But you want to keep all the exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one goes over the eitherList twice: 
1. For filtering out the exceptions
2. For removing duplicates based on a property.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_65).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> case class UserInfo(name: String, age: Int, email: String)
defined class UserInfo

scala> case class InvitePatternException(e: String) extends Throwable(e)
defined class InvitePatternException

scala> val eitherList: List[Either[InvitePatternException, UserInfo]] = 
List(
  Right(UserInfo("a",1,"a.mail.com")), 
  Right(UserInfo("b",1,"b.mail.com")), 
  Right(UserInfo("c",1,"a.mail.com")), 
  Right(UserInfo("d",5,"d.mail.com")), 
  Left(InvitePatternException("failed for user with name = d")), 
  Left(InvitePatternException("failed for user with name = e")), 
  Right(UserInfo("e",7,"a.mail.com"))
)

eitherList: List[Either[InvitePatternException,UserInfo]] = List(Right(UserInfo(a,1,a.mail.com)), Right(UserInfo(b,1,b.mail.com)), Right(UserInfo(c,1,a.mail.com)), Right(UserInfo(d,5,d.mail.com)), Left(InvitePatternException: failed for user with name = d), Left(InvitePatternException: failed for user with name = e), Right(UserInfo(e,7,a.mail.com)))

scala> val resultList = eitherList.filter(_.isLeft) ::: eitherList.collect { case Right(userInfo) => userInfo }.groupBy(_.email).map(_._2.head).map(Right(_)).toList
resultList: List[Either[InvitePatternException,UserInfo]] = List(Left(InvitePatternException: failed for user with name = d), Left(InvitePatternException: failed for user with name = e), Right(UserInfo(d,5,d.mail.com)), Right(UserInfo(a,1,a.mail.com)), Right(UserInfo(b,1,b.mail.com)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this more or less the same way as in any other programming language:  Keep a set of the things you've already seen, and skip an item if it's in the seen set (result types elided in the below to reduce noise):

```
scala> val items = Seq(
     Right(1), 
     Right(2), 
     Left(new Exception), 
     Left(new Exception), 
     Right(1), 
     Right(3)
)
items = List(Right(1), Right(2), Left(java.lang.Exception), Left(java.lang.Exception), Right(1), Right(3))

scala> val uniques = { 
    var seen = Set[Int](); 
    items.collect { 
      case Left(x) => Left(x); 
      case Right(i) if !seen(i) => 
        seen += i
        Right(i) 
    }
}
uniques = List(Right(1), Right(2), Left(java.lang.Exception), Left(java.lang.Exception), Right(3))
```

Don't forget that even though Scala programmers prefer immutable state, there is nothing inherently evil in using (locally) mutable state when that is the cleanest solution.